# How to display posts from specific category using get_option function?

Tags: categories, query

I try to display posts from specific category only in a author page, using get_option function like in the code below but it does not work:

```
<?php query_posts('cat='.get_option('admin_cat')); ?>
```

However, if using the id number, works perfect.

```
<?php query_posts( 'cat=6' ); ?>
```

How can I use get_option function  instead of ID number?

Later edit:

I apologize, it was my mistake that I wrote in admin option the category name instead of its id. 
However a code would be helpful to read both variants, like:

```
if admin option the category is an id
display its id
if in admin option category is a name
display its name
```

Thanks

Comment: in any case you shouldn't use query_posts. try doing a var_dump of your get_option call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the category name to search for categories. You can use the slug. Be aware of the difference. A slug is normalized to lower case with spaces replaced by dashes. The slug for "Foo A" would be "foo-a". Using "Foo A" will not work.

```
$admin_cat = get_option('admin_cat');

if (ctype_digit("$admin_cat")) { // this is an ID
  $qry = array('cat' => (int)$admin_cat);
} else {
  $qry = array('category_name' => $admin_cat);
}
$my_query = new WP_Query($qry);
```

As stated in a comment to your question, do not use [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts).

> It should be noted that using this to **replace the main query** on a page
>   can **increase page loading times**, in worst case scenarios **more than
>   doubling the amount of work needed or more**. While easy to use, the
>   function is also **prone to confusion and problems** later on. See the
>   note further below on caveats for details.
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts (emphasis mine)